# Redirect WWW to non-WWW without using a separate virtual server in Cherokee

Tags: web-server, redirection, cherokee

I'm using Cherokee webserver and I wish to redirect all requests to www.domain.com to domain.com without creating a separate virtual server to redirect requests.

In the `Host Match` section, I've set www.domain.com and domain.com as accepted domains in the wildcard mode. Now I assume that I need to create a rule with the `Redirection` handler with these settings:

```
Type: External
Regular Expression: ^/(.*)$
Substitution: http://domain.com/$1
```

The question is, what type of rule do I select? I've tried the redirection rule with this setting: `^www.domain.com/(.*)$`

### EDIT: ANSWER

#### (As ServerFault isn't letting me answer the question yet)

Finally figured it out. Create a rule of the `Header` type and pick the `Host` header. Then match this regular expression: `^www.domain.com$`. Set the handler to an external redirection with the Regular Expression: `^/(.*)$` and the Substitution: `http://domain.com/$1`.

Do a Graceful Restart and you should be all set!

Comment: I'm not a Cherokee admin, but from the looks of it, the redirection method you are trying to use does not use the `Host:` header, only the request URI.  Unless there's a header matching option for redirections, you probably cannot do your redirect like this.

Comment: @Derf You led me to the correct answer. I'll post it shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Create a rule of the `Header` type and pick the `Host` header. Then match this regular expression: `^www.domain.com$`. Set the handler to an external redirection with the Regular Expression: `^/(.*)$` and the Substitution: `http://domain.com/$1`.

Do a Graceful Restart and you should be all set!

Answer (score 1):

i was looking for something else, but noticed other searchers could use some advice.

**UNLESS** you want to actually change the address bar in the browser (i.e., from 'www.domain.tld' to 'domain.tld') AND waste bandwidth AND take more time to load, you should just let cherokee continue serving according to the 'match' setup that you can configure for any hosts -- such as 'www' -- that you have not set up in domain name service (DNS) as a CNAME resource record (RR) for your bare domain (domain.tld).

obviously, it far less expensive all round to use DNS to re-direct any hosts to the bare domain [i.e., make a DNS RR: 'host-name IN CNAME domain.tld.' NOTE the "." (dot) after '.tld']. even if you are in a constrained, shared hosting environment using someone else's nameservers, they always make available the capability to setup 'CNAME' RR's for your DNS.

so, this brings us to the question of why one is using any hosts at all. you can eliminate ambiguity by just having all your links going to domain.tld rather than host-name.domain.tld.

if you are concerned about search engine optimization (SEO): do not be. search engine "bots" start from the 'domain.tld' and DNS. also, they do not consider it a "good" thing when a server offers a re-direct. thus, prune your links and do the right thing in DNS and you will be much better off!